# Reference file in Ruby subshell in Rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble referencing a file in another directory in my rails app. I have a controller located in `my_app/app/controllers/concerns/my_controller` with the following line of code:

`@value = %x(python ../../lib/assets/python/test.py #{Shellwords.escape(params[:first_name])} 2>&1)`

That is running `test.py` located in `my_app/lib/assets/python/test.py` with the `%x()` subshell.

When I reference the file from my desktop, it runs the `test.py` code correctly. But when I place the script in my `lib/assets/python` folder I get a `cannot find file or directory` error.

How should I correctly reference my `test.py` file so that the `%x()` command can find it?

Comment: What is the environment of the user running the `%x(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PATH isn't set so the user running your code is able to find `python` then you'll get that error.

Instead of referencing it as `python` which forces the system to try to locate Python by walking the PATH, use the full path to the interpreter. You can usually find that by typing

```
which python
```

at the command prompt, and then putting that into the code replacing the single word `python`.

---

Ruby's File class has several *very* useful methods for finding the path from a directory to another, or to a specific file. Look at:

- [`absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-absolute_path)
- [`realpath`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-realpath)
- [`expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-expand_path)

I generally use `realpath` since it checks to see that the target actually exists before returning a path to it.

You could use it something like:

```
File.realpath('../../path/to/file', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

which should return a path relative to the script that is currently being executed.

You can reference from the running script using:

```
File.realpath('../../path/to/file', File.dirname($0))
```

You'll need to figure out whether you want to base your path from `__FILE__` or `$0` and what the differences are.

Comment: that works when I use the full file path to the `test.py` file, but how can I reference the file from within the app. `/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python /Users/me/workspace/my_app/lib/assets/python/test.py` works but, when I reference the file from within the app I get `/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python: can't open file '../../lib/assets/python/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: See the updated information about using File's methods.

Comment: I tried pretty much every combo I could think of and finally realized why it wasn't working, I needed to escape the `File.realpath` command. `@value = %x(/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python #{Shellwords.escape(File.absolute_path('lib/assets/python/test.py'))})`